# How To display post of a particular categories in a specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having different pages in navigation and I want post to be displayed in categories.
for example I am having a page latest news, and have made a categories new updates, then how can I make it work .. When I choose news updates as categories should display in the latest news page. And same for all other pages and categories

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer for this [Posts for Page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-for-page/) plugin. It is very simple to use for displaying post on page for specific category.

use this shortcode on pages

```
[posts-for-page cat_slug='your_specific_cat' hide_images='false' num='5' read_more='
Read More »']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [List category posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin for this. It allows shortcodes and you can display posts of a specific category with a shortcode like this:

```
[catlist id=1 numberposts=10]
```

where **id** is the Category ID and **numberposts** represents the number of posts you want to display on a page/post.

You can also wrap the output in a HTML tag and style it with CSS as required.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this template from twenty eleven. I must give great credit here to a great tutorial from [digitalraindrops](http://digitalraindrops.net/2011/09/wordpress-twenty-eleven-a-page-of-posts/). I have rewritten this to suite my needs and it is currently written to suite the twentyfourteen theme.

You can check out the tutorial at the link given above. What I like about this template is that it can be reused a thousand times. What this template do, it let you choose a category from a drop down list. This category's posts will then be displayed on that page. Here is the code that I use

First, all the meta functions that include options for posts per page, order, page title, post title, etc. This code will go in your functions.php or custom functions file

```
<?php
/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *Add a post metabox with options to the admin page screen.
 *After selcting the page-pop.php template as a page template,
 *this metabox will appear in the admin page screen.
 *From here you can choose which category's posts to display
 *and how the posts will be displayed on the page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *1. Only add meta boxes for the pop template
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('admin_init', 'pietergoosen_add_pop_meta_box');

function pietergoosen_add_pop_meta_box(){
$post_id = isset( $_GET['post'] ) ? $_GET['post'] : 0 ;
if($post_id) { 
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file == 'page-pop.php') { 
add_meta_box('pop_meta_box', __( 'Page of Posts with the same name', 'pietergoosen' ), 'pietergoosen_pop_meta_options', 'page', 'side', 'core');
} else {
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', true);
if( $meta ) {
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_page_title', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_posts_title', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_by', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_asc', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_post_count', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_days', '');
remove_meta_box( 'pop_meta_box', 'page', 'side' );
}
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta_box');
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *2. Built the list to display the options in the metabox
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$order_list = array(
'none' => array( 'value' => 'none','label' => 'None' ),
'id' => array( 'value' => 'ID','label' => 'Post ID' ),
'author' => array( 'value' => 'author','label' => 'Author' ),
'title' => array( 'value' => 'title','label' => 'Post Title' ),
'date' => array( 'value' => 'date', 'label' => 'Post Date'),
'modified' => array( 'value' => 'modified','label' => 'Modified Date' ),
'parent' => array( 'value' => 'parent','label' => 'Parent Post' ),
'rand' => array( 'value' => 'rand','label' => 'Random' ),
'comment_count' => array( 'value' => 'comment_count','label' => 'Comment Count' ),
'menu_order' => array( 'value' => 'menu_order','label' => 'Menu Order' ),
);

$sort = array(
'DESC' => array( 'value' => 'DESC','label' => 'Descending' ),
'ASC' => array( 'value' => 'ASC','label' => 'Ascending' ),
); 

function pietergoosen_pop_meta_options(){

$post_id = !empty($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : 0;
if( !$post_id ) return;

$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file != 'page-pop.php') return;

global $order_list,$post_styles,$sort;
$categories = get_categories();

//Check if we have values
$post_meta=array();
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id,false );

$cat_id = isset( $post_meta['_cat_id'] ) ? $post_meta['_cat_id'][0] : 1;
$page_title = isset( $post_meta['_page_title'] ) && $post_meta['_page_title'] ? $post_meta['_page_title'][0] : '';
$posts_title = isset( $post_meta['_posts_title'] ) && $post_meta['_posts_title'] ? $post_meta['_posts_title'][0] : '';
$order_by = isset( $post_meta['_order_by'] ) ? $post_meta['_order_by'][0] : 'date';
$asc = isset( $post_meta['_asc'] ) ? $post_meta['_asc'][0] : 'DESC';
$post_count = isset( $post_meta['_post_count'] ) ? $post_meta['_post_count'][0] : get_option('posts_per_page');
if(!$post_count || !is_numeric( $post_count )) $post_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
$days = isset( $post_meta['_days'] ) ? $post_meta['_days'][0] : '0';
if($days && !is_numeric( $days )) $days = '0';
?>

<!-- Sart the meta boxes -->
<div class="inside">
<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Page Title', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
<input id="_posts_title" name="_posts_title" type="text" style="width: 98%;" value="<?php echo $posts_title; ?>"/>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Post Title', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
<input id="_page_title" name="_page_title" type="text" style="width: 98%;" value="<?php echo $page_title; ?>"/>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Category', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
<select id="_cat_id" name="_cat_id">
<?php 
//Category List
foreach ($categories as $cat) :
$selected = ( $cat->cat_ID == $cat_id ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
$option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $cat->cat_ID;
$option = $option .'">';
$option = $option .$cat->cat_name;
$option = $option .'</option>';
echo $option;
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Sort by', 'pietergoosen' )?></strong></label></p>
<select id="_order_by" name="_order_by">
<?php 
foreach ($order_list as $output) :
$selected = ( $output['value'] == $order_by ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
$option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $output['value'];
$option = $option .'">';
$option = $option .$output['label'];
$option = $option .'</option>';
echo $option;
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Order', 'pietergoosen' )?><strong></label></p>
<select id="_asc" name="_asc">
<?php 
foreach ($sort as $output) :
$selected = ( $output['value'] == $asc ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
$option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $output['value'];
$option = $option .'">';
$option = $option .$output['label'];
$option = $option .'</option>';
echo $option;
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<p><strong><label><?php _e( 'Posts per Page', 'pageofposts' ); ?><strong></label></p>
<input id="_post_count" name="_post_count" type="text" value="<?php echo $post_count; ?>" size="3" />

<p><strong><label><?php _e( 'Posts in the last days', 'pageofposts' ); ?><strong></label></p>
<input id="_days" name="_days" type="text" value="<?php echo $days; ?>" size="3" />
</div>
<!-- End page of posts meta box -->
<?php
}
function pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta_box( $post_id ){

if ( empty( $_POST ) ) {
return;
} else {
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file != 'page-pop.php') return;

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
return $post_id;
} else {
if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'page' ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
  return $post_id;
} else {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
  return $post_id;
}
$meta = isset( $_POST['_cat_id'] ) ? $_POST['_cat_id'] : 1;
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_page_title'] ) ? $_POST['_page_title'] : '';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_page_title', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_posts_title'] ) ? $_POST['_posts_title'] : '';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_posts_title', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_order_by'] ) ? $_POST['_order_by'] : 'date';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_by', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_asc'] ) ? $_POST['_asc'] : 'DESC';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_asc', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_post_count'] ) ? $_POST['_post_count'] : get_option('posts_per_page');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_post_count', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_days'] ) ? $_POST['_days'] : 0;
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_days', $meta);
return;
}
}
}

function pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data) {
$post_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
if( $data != '' && $post_meta != $data) {
update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data);
} elseif ( $post_meta != '' && $data == '' ) {
delete_post_meta($post_id, $key);
}
}
?>
```

Secondly, the page template. You have to call this template `page-pop.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page of Posts
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
//See if we have any values
$post_meta=array();
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID,false );
$catid = isset( $post_meta['_cat_id'] ) ? $post_meta['_cat_id'][0] : 1;
$page_title = isset( $post_meta['_page_title'] ) ? $post_meta['_page_title'][0] : '';
$posts_title = isset( $post_meta['_posts_title'] ) ? $post_meta['_posts_title'][0] : '';
$orderby = isset( $post_meta['_order_by'] ) ? $post_meta['_order_by'][0] : 'date';
$asc = isset( $post_meta['_asc'] ) ? $post_meta['_asc'][0] : 'DESC';
$list_style =  isset( $post_meta['_list_style'] ) ? $post_meta['_list_style'][0] : 'default';
$post_count = isset( $post_meta['_post_count'] ) ? $post_meta['_post_count'][0] : get_option('posts_per_page');
if(!$post_count || !is_numeric( $post_count )) $post_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
$days = isset( $post_meta['_days'] ) ? $post_meta['_days'][0] : 0;
if($days && !is_numeric( $days )) $days = 0;
$do_not_show_stickies = ($list_style == 'default') ? 0 : 1;
?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

<!-- Page Title -->
<?php if( $posts_title ) : ?>
<article id="posts-title">
<header class="entry-header">
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo $posts_title; ?></h2>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
</article><!-- #posts-title -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php global $post;
if( $post->post_content || $page_title ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if( $page_title ) : ?>
<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( $post->post_content ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-meta">

</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
<?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php 
/* Do we have any category */
global $post;

// Save posts for later use
$tmp_post = $post;

$args = array( 
'cat' => $catid,
'posts_per_page' => $post_count,
'paged' => $paged,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'order' => $asc,
'ignore_sticky_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies,
);

if( $days ) {
function pop_filter_where( $where = '') {
global $days;
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' .$days .' days')) . "'";
return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'pop_filter_where' );
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'pop_filter_where' );
} else {
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args );
}
// Output
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :

// Start the Loop.
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 

endwhile;

pietergoosen_pagination();

else : 

get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

endif; ?>

<?php 
// Reset the post to the page post
$post = $tmp_post; 
?>

    <?php if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
comments_template();
} ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>

</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

You can now simply create a new page and choose the "page of posts" template, and publish your page. Once that is done, the Page of Posts metabox will appear. From that you can choose the category to display on that page. Hope this helps you